# Cannot resolve symbol raw when the folder is empty

Tags: android, android-resources

Why is it giving me "cannot resolve symbol raw" when i try to access the folder with the following code `Field[]fields=R.raw.class.getFields();`

The same code works when i add any file to the raw folder. The folder is in "res" directory.

**Note:** I have tried using the complete package name also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an `Android resource folder` such as `layout`, `drawable`, `mipmap`, etc.. The android will create a file named `R.java`. You can find it in

`app\build\generated\source\r\degug\your\app\package\name\R.java`.

It basically a normal java file which has been generated by android automatically for referring resources by ids in our code.

**R.java**

```
public final class R {
    public static final class layout{
        public static final int main_activity=0x7f0a0000;
        public static final int login_activity=0x7f0a0001;
    }
    public static final class drawable{
        public static final int ic_add=0x7f0a0000;
        public static final int ic_edit=0x7f0a0001;
    }
    public static final class mimap{
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f0b0000;
    }
}
```

From Android official site:

> Resources are the additional files and static content that your code
>   uses, such as bitmaps, layout definitions, user interface strings,
>   animation instructions, and more.

It means `res` folder is `read-only` and you cannot modify (add, update, delete) the content side.

Back to your problem, when you create `raw` folder but do not put any files inside and android know that in the runtime you cannot modify this folder as well, so why we need to create a refer to the `raw` resources anymore. It does not make sense. Because there is no `raw` class in `R.java` so your compiler display the error.

```
cannot resolve symbol raw
```

But if you create a file and put into `raw` folder, then after build process, a class `raw` will be created in `R.java` file.

```
public final class R {
    public static final class layout{
        public static final int main_activity=0x7f0a0000;
        public static final int login_activity=0x7f0a0001;
    }
    public static final class drawable{
        public static final int ic_add=0x7f0a0000;
        public static final int ic_edit=0x7f0a0001;
    }
    public static final class mimap{
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f0b0000;
    }

    public static final class raw {
        public static final int sound=0x7f0b0000;
    }
}
```

And now the error gone.

Comment: Hi great answer although the error goes immediately after i put any file, no need for a build

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using wrong package of **R**.
Make sure R should be from your package name rather then some other android Native class.

Comment: i have mentioned that i have tried using the package name, i have made sure that the package name is write, also if the package name was wrong how did it work when i added a sample file to it